# ocserv could not execute script for the incoming connection

Tags: openconnect, ocserv

```
connect-script = /app/connect.sh
disconnect-script = /app/disconnect.sh
```

I have the above configuration in my **ocserv.conf** in the docker container, but ocserv fails to execute **/app/connect.sh** when there is a connection. I cann't find the real cause from the following log, has anyone had the same issue?

```
ocserv[26]: main[test]:xxx.xxx.179.135:57352 user of group 'Route' authenticated (using cookie)
ocserv[29]: main[test]:xxx.xxx.179.135:57352 executing script up /app/connect.sh
ocserv[29]: main[test]:xxx.xxx.179.135:57352 main-user.c:379: Could not execute script /app/connect.sh
ocserv[26]: main[test]:xxx.xxx.179.135:57352 connect-script exit status: 1
ocserv[26]: main[test]:xxx.xxx.179.135:57352 failed authentication attempt for user 'test'
```

The content of /app/connect.sh:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "$(date) [info] User ${USERNAME} Connected - Server: ${IP_REAL_LOCAL} VPN IP: ${IP_REMOTE}  Remote IP: ${IP_REAL} Device:${DEVICE}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured it out myself that the docker container I created doesn't have bash, and one solution is to substitute `#!/bin/bash` with `#!/bin/sh`.